# python help with extracting value from list

Tags: list, dictionary, python

```
lst = [{"id": 1, "name": "ernest"}, .... {"id": 16, name:"gellner"}]

for d in lst:
    if "id" in d and d["id"] == 16:
        return d
```

I want to extract the dictionary that the key "id" equals to "16" from the list.

Is there a more pythonic way of this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @TokenMacGuy well yeah I actually meant 16, I just didn't notice that I'll edit it

Comment: I think this is good enough. Anything more would be over-complicating things.

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be a list? Because I would say that the _most_ pythonic solution would be to use a different data structure. Querying a list like this is always inefficient. Unless there's a clear reason why you need a list of dictionaries, I would recommend using a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: @senderle I am building a tree of nodes, that's why I have to use lists since dictionaries are not sorted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riffing on existing answers to get out of the comments:

Consider using a generator expression when you only need the first matching element out of a sequence:

```
d16 = (d for d in lst if d.get('id') == 16).next()
```

This is a pattern you'll see in my code often.  This will raise a `StopIteration` if it turns out there weren't any items in `lst` that matched the condition.  When that's expected to happen, you can either catch the exception:

```
try:
    d16 = (d for d in lst if d.get('id') == 16).next()
except StopIteration:
    d16 = None
```

Or better yet, just unroll the whole thing into a for-loop that *stops*

```
for d16 in lst:
    if d16.get('id') == 16:
        break
else:
    d16 = None
```

(the `else:` clause only gets run if the for loop exhausts its input, but gets skipped if the for loop ends because `break` was used)

Comment: I just tested @g.d.d.c 's answer and compared it with mine. There is a huge performance difference. Tested with a million dictionaries in a list and while his method returns back a value in 0.20 seconds the one that I provided in the question returns back only in a 0.01 sec. Am I doing something wrong or its actually true?

Comment: Now things change, your generator expression works as fast as mine and its only one line. When you search the id 999 from a list that includes ids from 0 to 1 million it returns back the value in a 0.01 sec, so basically same as mine. But the thing is that, if you don't mind try and catch its only one sentence. Therefore I'll shift my answer from gddc to yours! Thanks!

Comment: From a strictly efficiency point of view, the only thing your original solution could use is substituting `d.get('id') == 16` in favor of `'id' in d and d['id'] == 16`.  otherwise, yours actually *should* be faster.  Often, questions like "more pythonic" result in answers that are "clever in some way", but not always "as efficient for my problem as possible".  be careful what you ask for.

Answer (score 2):

This does it.  Whether or not it's "cleaner" is a personal call.

```
d16 = [d for d in lst if d.get('id', 0) == 16][0]
```

This initial approach fails if there is no dictionary with id 0.  You can overcome that somewhat like this:

```
d16 = [d for d in lst if d.get('id', 0) == 16]
if d16: d16 = d16[0]
```

This will prevent the index error, but d16 will be an empty list if there is no dictionary in the container that matches the criteria.

Comment: Note please that this could produce an IndexError if there is no dictionary in lst that has an id value of 16.

Comment: well what if I add and 'if d["id"]' before 'd.get("id", 0)' ?

Comment: @Shaokan - `d.get(<key>[, <default>])` already takes care of that.  The problem isn't in the list comprehension, it's in the `[0]` after it - if the list comprehension produces an empty list (because no dictionary has id 0) then attempting to retrieve position 0 of the resulting list will raise an error.

Comment: hmm I got it. So I guess I should use this statement within a try catch bloc?

Comment: @Shaokan - slightly modified up above.  HTH.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy this gives a StopIteration error, or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One slight improvement if not found:

```
d16 = ([d for d in lst if d.get('id', 0) == 16] + [None])[0]
```